# Using Android Studio flavors with a project created in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, android-productflavors

I'm trying to apply flavors to a big project my company started when **Android Studio** wasn't a thing. Remaking the project from scratch is not an option and directly importing it to **Android Studio** did not work in the first place, we had to do a lot of work for it to work.

Now we are trying to use flavors with is, but we have the old **Eclipse** project structure and I'm at a loss.

How can I achieve this? I just want to swap a configuration class between release and debug apks.

Comment: see this link http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/

Comment: Why import directly to Android Studio didn't work? When you move to gradle system you have only to change dependencies, buildscript, something in the manifest and you finally can add flavors. I think that you don't need that much time to do it

Comment: Because we use loads of NDK stuff and obscure shit to make DRM work.